# Is it possible in quarto to create custom cross-references to callout blocks?

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, quarto

#### Task

I'm using `quarto` to write an online book and need to mimic the environments and counters of a published book. The latter employs five custom framed environments (examples, exercises, remarks, theorems, definitions) with a joined counter (within the chapter).

I'm considering to use the readily available [callout blocks](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/callouts.html) for these because these are styled quite nicely by default. I haven't been successful, though, to create a custom counter for these callout blocks so that I can cross-reference from the text. Is there a way to do so?

*(Remark: I've also tried to do this via standard amsthm environments provided through `quarto`, see [Shared counter in quarto for exercises, examples, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73288264/shared-counter-in-quarto-for-exercises-examples-etc).)*

#### Demo

I would have hoped that something like the following existed so that I can create a new `#callout` counter. But I couldn't find infrastructure for this:

```
The first definition is @callout-1.

:::{.callout-note}
## Definition {#callout-1}
This should be Definition 1.1.
:::

It is followed by the first example, @callout-2

:::{.callout-tip}
## Example {#callout-2}
This should be Example 1.2.
:::
```

Because this doesn't work like this `quarto` renders this to:

[image: callout block example as rendered by quarto]

But what I'm looking for is a result like this:

[image: callout block example with desired rendered (mimicked manually)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for a workaround in a similar that allows me to define groups of jointly numbered environments (for html and pdf) without extra hacks. I put my solution in an [extension](https://github.com/ute/custom-numbered-blocks). It does for the time being only support crossreference by \ref, and maybe it becomes obsolete with quarto 1.4?
You can modify the appearance / colors for each type of environment from the yaml.

```
filters:
  - custom-numbered-blocks
custom-numbered-blocks:
  groups: 
    thmgroup: 
      boxstyle: foldbox.simple
      collapse: false
  classes:
    Example:
      group: thmgroup
    Definition:
      group: thmgroup
      colors: [cce7b1, 86b754]
```

Then

```
# First Section

The first definition is Definition \ref{mydef}

::: {.Definition #mydef}

This should be Definition \ref{mydef}

:::

It is followed by the first example, Example \ref{myexpl}

::: {.Example #myexpl}

### an example for Definition \ref{mydef}

This should be Example \ref{myexpl}
:::
```

renders in html

[image: rendered example, html]

or in pdf

[image: rendered example, pdf]

To change the overall appearance of the boxes, you would currently need to modify a css  / tex file.

The extension is here: https://github.com/ute/custom-numbered-blocks

Comment: This is really neat! Will have to play around some more to customize it for our needs but it seems that this might work for our book. Quick follow-up question: Which LaTeX parameter do I need to tweak to get the bottom right corner of the box fully closed?

Comment: Thank you! I was also unhappy with the hole in the bottom right corner, so I fixed it., finally. There was one option too much ("arc=0pt"). I've updated the extension on github.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I was able to do this was to add an ID to the callout

```
::: {#callout-1 .callout-note}
## Definition {#callout-1}
This should be Definition 1.1.
:::
```

And then manually call it in your markdown through:

```
Please refer to the [note 1](#callout-1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, good to know. This addresses the problem of creating a hyperlink but I would have to do the counter in some other way (e.g., hard-coding), right?

Comment: Does your link actually take you anywhere? If I use this code I do get a link but it's unresponsive.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer Examples or Exercises within callout blocks by extending [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73304425/10858321) to your other question related to this question, like this,

```
# Introduction


The first example is @exm-1.

::: {#exm-1}
This should be Example 1.1.
:::

It is followed by the first exercise, [Exercise @exm-2]

::: {#exm-2 .custom}
This should be Exercise 1.2.
:::


:::: {.callout-note}

::: {#exm-3}
This should be Example 1.3
:::

::::

:::: {.callout-tip}

::: {#exm-4 .custom}
This should be Exercise 1.4
:::

::::

Please refer to the @exm-3

Please refer to the [Exercise @exm-4]
```

and add these two lines in your project yaml `_quarto.yaml`

**_quarto.yaml**

```
callout-appearance: simple
callout-icon: false
```

---

The rendered output looks like,

[image: custom_callout_reference]

---

***Again, Note that when you want to render the Example environments as Exercise, use the `.custom` class, so that the javascript code [written in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73304425/10858321) will apply.***

Also, you can also write javascript code to handle the `Definition` tag in the same way as this.